# NSDate for current date is different?

Tags: swift3, nsdate

I was trying to get the next date when I noticed something interesting to me. When I do

```
let date = NSDate()
let calender = NSCalendar.current
let components = calender.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: date as Date)
    dateLabel.text = "\(components.month!)/\(components.day!)/\(components.year!)"
```

I get thedate I want, which is the current date.

However, when I do

```
@IBAction func nextDate(_ sender: UIButton) {

    var oneDayfromNow: NSDate {
        return NSCalendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: NSDate() as Date)! as NSDate
    }
    print("Current Date: \(calender)")
    print(oneDayfromNow)
}
```

on my print with the current date I actually get the next date's date and my oneDayfromNow variable is the date 2 days from now. So in short, my current date for my two blocks are different.

Can someone explain to me why is that?

THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quote from apple developer website about **NSDate**,

> NSDate objects encapsulate a single point in time, independent of any
>   particular calendrical system or time zone. Date objects are
>   immutable, representing an invariant time interval relative to an
>   absolute reference date (00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001).

So, it means that it does not dictate time in any particular region, rather it is an opaque object which denotes some particular time. It is rather the responsibility of NSDateFormatter to format date and represent it to the timezone that you want it in.

Answer (score 0):

You know I used to recognize something similar. All my `Date` values were always 8 hours ahead (I live in Northern California).

Check out something called "ISO 8601"

[ISO 8601 - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

I don't know if you're familiar with Zulu time or what's now known as UTC (Universal Time Coordinates I think), but it's a universal time that ignores time zones.

You're probably still getting the correct date and time, they are just reflected with UTC.